# Docker connection to PostgreSQL failing from host

Tags: postgresql, docker

Spent quite sometime on this but no breakthrough. This is my container creation statement:

```
> docker create --name aasaan_db_dev -e POSTGRES_USER=aasaan -e
> POSTGRES_PASSWORD=aasaan_admin --expose 5432 postgres:9.4.0
> 
> > deepakkt@deepakkt-ubuntu:~$ docker ps
> 
> CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                 
> CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
> 15b21deb19a0        postgres:9.4.0      "/docker-entrypoin..."   About
> an hour ago   Up About an hour    5432/tcp            aasaan_db_dev
```

The following works:

```
> deepakkt@deepakkt-ubuntu:~$ docker exec -it aasaan_db_dev psql -U
> aasaan psql (9.4.0) Type "help" for help.
> 
> aasaan=#
```

However, from the host (same error from pgAdmin as well)

```
> deepakkt@deepakkt-ubuntu:~$ psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U aasaan 
Password for user aasaan:  
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user
> "aasaan" FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "aasaan"
```

Contents of *pg_hba.conf* inside the container:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                trust
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            trust
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 trust

host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker ps` is showing `5432/tcp` for your port section.
This means the port `5432` is opened on your postgres container. (This is by default because it's exposed in the Dockerfile of postgres so you don't need the `--expose` command).

The name of your container is `aasaan_db_dev`. Other containers which are deployed in the same bridge network can access your container using `aasaan_db_dev:5432`.

But your container is not mapping it's port to the outside which means you can not access the container from outside the bridge network. (for example not from `eth0`).

To map your port use the following command:

```
docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d -p 5432:5432 postgres
```

In this case the `-p` option will map `5432` from your container on `5432` of your host. Now you should be able to connect to the container from your host network (for example localhost).

Comment: noted. i had another issue wherein a local (non-docker) install of postgres was interfering with port 5432 as well. it thought i had removed it but it was still lurking around. cleaning that up and running with -p worked!

Answer (score 2):

It is needed to map the container port to host port.

Have a look at below docker documentation:

> The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It
>   functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the
>   image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are
>   intended to be published. To actually publish the port when running
>   the container, use the -p flag on docker run to publish and map one or
>   more ports, or the -P flag to publish all exposed ports and map them
>   to high-order ports.

Source: [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose)

Comment: your answer helped me. However in its current state it is partial. If you can update the answer with the proper command, I will accept it. What happened was that an earlier installtion on host was conflicting with port 5432. I cleaned that up and did -P as you mentioned and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You should not use 127.0.0.1 as it will refer to your localhost. But actually, it is running on a container.

You should use

```
psql -h <imagename> -U <username>
```

You need to provide port as well.